# Preserve page's state after clicking on browser's back button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

I have a form with a text input in it. After submitting the form and clicking on the browser's back button in Google Chrome (desktop and mobile), I can see my entered value but the JavaScript code at the end of my HTML document returns an empty value. I tested my code on Firefox (desktop and mobile) and at first it seemed OK. Although I can get the value in Firefox, but the value added to the `bar` is not preserved after pressing the back button. How can I fix that?

Apparently using [pageshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event) event solves the problem.

Another thing I learnt today is that using `autocomplete="off"` prevents browser from remembering the entered value.

```js
const foo = document.getElementById("foo");
const bar = document.getElementById("bar");
foo.addEventListener("input", () => {
  bar.textContent = foo.value;
});

console.log("Input value: " + foo.value);
console.log("Just a random number: " + Math.random());
```

```html
<form action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="bar"></p>
```

Comment: You'll have to show a [mcve] first, otherwise people will just be guessing at the problem, and guesses are not answers.

Comment: Is this because when you click back _javascript isn't ran again_? The log you see might just be the log of the previous page load when the input was empty. This tends to happen when pressing back. You should run your code _again_ to see if the value if still understood to be empty.

Comment: @somethinghere I edited the code to make sure JavaScript is ran again.